# Cucumber features won't run under Lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, osx-lion

So I had a couple rails apps with cucumber features on my Macbook Pro when I did the in-place upgrade for Lion.

So now I have XCode reinstalled, updated all my gems, and when I start the rails server everything seems to be good to go. But if I run `cucumber features` I get the following:

```
You have already activated rack 1.3.2, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.2.3. 
Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)
```

So I deleted Gemfile.lock to get rid of the old gem list, bumped the rails version on Gemfile to the new one, and ran `bundle install` again, and it did it's thing. No errors, but the cucumber features will not run for the life of me.

Comment: Have you considered using `bundle exec cucumber` instead of running `cucumber`?:)

Comment: I'll give that a shot, but I'd like to figure out whats wrong with my environment as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your environment is fine and you always should user bundle exec if you want to execute a gem binary, in this case it will always start executable of version that is declared in Gemfile, in other case without bundle exec it will start binary from version installed in your system, sometimes they could match (but it is only coincidence).

Add something like that to your profile to avoid long command call:

`alias bec='bundle exec cucumber -r features'`